# Empty Derived Class inherited from Non-Empty Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, empty-class

```
class Base 
{
   int i ;
};

class Derived : public Base { } ;

int main()
{
   cout << sizeof(Derived);
}

Output :
 4
```

In Base class , since i is private , it should not be inherited to the Derived Class . Hence , the Base class should act as empty class . And sizeof empty class is 1 , then why it is showing as 4 ?

Comment: Why should the `sizeof` an empty class be 1?  BTW, it's not empty.

Comment: "...since i is private , it should not be inherited..." - nonsense!!!

Comment: P.S. if you really believe that `i` would not be inherited since its' private,  - then why does your `Derived` inherit it in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

A `Derived` class still contains `i` in `Base`, it just isn't accessible, so the size 4 is because of `i`

Answer (score 0):

The size still is 4 because the size of `Base` is 4. Lets say for example that `Base` has a function
    `public:
    int getI() {return i;}`
then you are able to call `Derived::getI()`, therefore Derived does need to include the private base members.

Answer (score -2):

here,derived class is defined publicly.. means here in definition ": public base"

thus derived class can access all public as well as private members of base class..it will make all private members public in that derived class..thus output is 4 coz of i.not 1.if u write private instead then it will give output 1..